# GIT: For loop on local branches

Tags: git

I want to iterate through all my local branches and perform the following actions;

1. Switch to a branch
2. Do some operations. (Like re-writing the cache entries)
3. Push that branch

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? You could create a powershell script to perform this.

Comment: For which operating system / environment?

Answer (score 4):

Using [`git for-each-ref`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref):

```
git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' refs/heads |
    while read branch; do
        git checkout $branch
        # Do something with the code
    done

# Push all branches at once instead of pushing them one by one
git push --all
```

Answer (score 0):

using `bash`:

```
for branch in $(git branch | sed 's/* /  /')
do
    git checkout $branch
    # here do the operations you want to do on each branch.
done
```

NOTE: `git branch | sed 's/* /  /')` lists branches but removes the asterisk (`*`)

Comment: While this iterates over all branches, it will also iterate over all files of the current directory, as `git branch` marks the current branch with a `* ` prefix. That prefix then gets expanded by sh to all files in the current directory. This might actually be harmful, as `git checkout $filename` will reset the content of $filename, if there are uncommitted changes.

Comment: @LariaChabowski great remark. Sloppy of me. I have corrected this.

Answer (score 0):

I actually have a `bash` function that should be pretty easy to modify to your needs. It's called `gsync`, and basically synchronises all the branches for which I have a local copy. The output of the `git br` is one branch name for all branches with the exception that my current branch also has a `*` at the start of the line.

So I use that to get the current branch and first process all the other braches, so that I end up back in the same branch I started in.

```
function gsync {
    old="$(git branch | awk 'NF==2{print $2}')"

    for i in $(git branch | awk 'NF==1{print}') ; do
        printf "\n===== $i\n"
        git co $i && git pull
    done
    printf "\n===== $old\n"
    git co $old && git pull
    printf "\n=====\n"
    git branch
}
```

Here's a sample run:

```
[~/myrepo]> gsync

===== PaxBranch-42
Switched to branch 'PaxBranch-42'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/PaxBranch-42'.
Already up to date.

===== master
Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
Already up to date.

=====

  PaxBranch-42
* master
```

Comment: You should publish the definition for `git br` or replace it with a proper `git` command. Is it just your local alias for `git branch`?

Comment: @phd, yes it was. Fixed now.